# Joining each element of a list to another element in Python

Tags: python

I have written a piece of code as given below.

```
import math 
import numpy

Theta = 0.5 
cList = numpy.arange(-10, 10, 0.05) 
NList = [5,10,100,1000]

for N in NList:
    for c in cList:
        math.floor(Theta + float(c*Theta*(1-Theta))/float(math.sqrt(N))
```

The last line, for each N in NList and c in cList produces an integer. For such integer produced, I want to create a list starting from 0 to that number, and calculate `(N choose K)*(0.5)^N` for each element of that list and then sum them.

For instance, let say for some N in NList and c in CList, the last gives 5. Then I want to get a list from 0 to 5, which is `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and calculate `(N choose k)*(0.5)^N` for each of `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and then sum the calculated values.

Not sure how to do that. It would be great if someone can help me with that. I tried using range functions etc. but not sure how to do `0,5` and then apply list to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for x in range(5):
...   print x
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> sum(x * 2 for x in range(5))
20
```